# index.html file is not reading main.css file for only chrome (desktop)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, adblock

My website is hosted by 000webhostapp.com.  It is working in all browsers (Moz, Opera and mobile) except desktop chrome. There is no error in W3C validator and all path and links are correctly written. What maybe a reason?

[in Chrome desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR2Fi.png)

[DT(F12) console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvWgA.png)

Comment: do you have errors in your browser console?

Comment: What do the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser say? You should see some request under the Network tab or an error present in the console indicating why it may not be loading.

Comment: it says: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit here is AdBlock. More precisely, [EasyList](https://easylist.to/) filter list that is applied to AdBlock's filter sets by default.

There's a following rule inside that set which says: *Block any resource where URL matches to `/adx`, but not for domains `adx.uk.com` or `adx.wowfi.com`.*

```
/adx.$domain=~adx.uk.com|~adx.wowfi.com
```

In your case it matches a part of your domain name: *http:/`/adx`.000webhostapp.com/css/normalize.css*

You can find every blocked resource on [AdBlock tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoAHS.jpg) in your browser's Developer Tools.

## How to solve this?

The best way to solve this is to contact EasyList authors and inform them about incorrectly blocked content. According to their website, the preferred way is to write on [their forum](https://forums.lanik.us/viewforum.php?f=64) (registration is not required).

Another way is to serve every resource (styles, scripts, images) from different domain that will not get caught up in the filter.

Yet another way, tho not recommended, is to ignore this issue or entirely change your domain name.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into it and it seems the problem is adblock, I tried disabling my adblock on chrome and it worked just fine so maybe look into why adblock is stopping you from loading your css or just put in something that tells the user to disable the adblock.

More information here: https://www.keycdn.com/support/how-to-solve-err-blocked-by-client/